# I need help showing this inequality

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f'>0$, $f''<0$, and $f(0)=0$. I need to show, that for every $x>0$:

$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}>x$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f^\prime >0$ this is equivalent to 
$$f(x)-xf^\prime(x) >0$$
For $x=0$ this expression is $=0$. Differentiating we get
$$f^\prime (x) -f^\prime(x) -xf^{\prime\prime}(x) = -xf^{\prime\prime}(x)> 0$$
for $x>0$ by assumption. Hence $f(x)-xf^\prime(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$.

Comment: Why is the expression $=0$ when $x=0$?

Comment: @JohnHabert Just plug in the assummption $f(0)=0$.

Comment: And I am having trouble reading. I read the condition as $f(0)=0.1$. Sorry for the silly question.